# warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I have a function named

```
void *func(void *arg)
{
    ///does some operation
}
```

Now I am getting a compiler warning that  "control reaches end of non-void function" even though i declare the return type as `void *`.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix up this warning?

Comment: Please post all your code, at least a working sample.

Answer (score 3):

The return type is `void *`, that means that you will return a pointer. Perhaps you wanted to type `void`, which means that you will not return anything?

Comment: Maybe he is bound to this function signature by a callback. Then he cannot change this but simply should `return NULL;`?

Comment: @Andrea..It was actually void func(void) before,But i had changed the prototype to void * func(void *arg) because to avoid the warning which i got for the 3rd parameter for pthread_create function.

Comment: @Nobody...returning a NULL..does it have any other consequences.Is returning NULL the same as the use of void *?

Comment: The value returned from a function used as argument of `pthread_create` is useful if you have to do a `pthread_join` or similar. Otherwise, ignore it. Also, take a look at [the documentation of `pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html).

Comment: You need to return something; any pointer value would be fine. `NULL` is the easiest. Passing a function with the wrong signature (with or without a cast) to `pthread_create` results in undefined behavior - you should never do it. Just accept that the "useless" `return NULL;` is required.

Comment: @R..: NULL is not only the easiest for passing back but also in means of debugging the code. When you return something other than NULL and do not remember it you could find yourself later handling some pointer that could be valid. A NULL pointer never will be valid so you can find the origin of the error faster.

Answer (score 0):

We need all the code to truly see what is going on, but he compiler cannot tell from that code if the function will ever reach the end and still return something. You said it would return a pointer -- a `void*` -- and returned nothing. That isn't a void function, that is a `void*` function. The compiler is expecting you to return a `void*`, but instead you just fall off the end of the function.

You may also have an infinite `while` loop, which the compiler is smart enough to know that the function will not return, but this is pure speculation because you did not post all the code.